# iOS - Possible to get filename, date, etc, from UIImagePickerController Delegate?

Tags: ios, delegates, filenames

I'm wondering if it's possible to get filename, date, and filesize, from the UIImagePickerController Delegate in iOS 4.3?  For both video and images?

I did some research on some forums but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can access file's metadata from UIImagePickerController, but there is AssetsLibrary framework which allows you to access actual image's metadata. Hope this help :D

Comment: Great, thanks.  If you have an ALAsset, you can use defaultRespresentation to get most infos.